# Change link color of eqref

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing, color

I am trying to change the link color made with `\eqref` to be different from the other `\ref` links. I have this

```
\makeatletter
\let\reftagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces\textcolor{blue}
{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\reftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

But it only changes the color of the number in the equation. Could you help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Instead of posting code fragments, please put your fragment into a complete, compilable document that starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}` that shows the problem.

Comment: I’ve not tested it, but I’d say that your code snippet changes the color of *all* equation numbers, not only when they appear as a reference.

Comment: I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: have you tried applying the color to *only* the redefinition of `\eqref`?

Comment: how do I do that @barbarabeeton ?

Answer (score 7):

If all parts of a reference should appear in a specific color, the command `\color` in a group in conjunction with `\hypersetup` for `linkbordercolor` comes into action.

Store the definition of `\eqref` first in, say, `\@msm@th@ref`, then use

```
\begingroup\leavevmode\color{violet}...
\@msm@th@eqref
\endgroup
```

in a redefined `\eqref` macro.

This will use `violet` as color for parentheses, reference value and link.

Another option is to use `mathtools` and `\newtagform`, this will change the number of the equation in place however. (This option is not shown here)

(About the usage of `\leavevmode` see the comment by `egreg` below. Thanks to him to point to this possible issue).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\let\@msm@th@eqref\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \color{violet}%
  \hypersetup{linkbordercolor=[named]{violet}}%
  \@msm@th@eqref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Foo} \label{section::foo}
\begin{equation}
a \equiv a\label{eq::foo}
\end{equation}


See the important \eqref{eq::foo} but look also at \ref{section::foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for safety, there should be `\leavevmode` before `\color{violet}`.

Comment: @egreg: Hm, I missed this feature so far. Doesn't `\color` work in `\vmode`?

Comment: It can be issued in vertical mode, but when it's used for typesetting a specific piece of text, it's safer when a paragraph has already begun.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I added it with a reference to your explanation

Comment: Neither of these options worked for me, looking at the error that I got:
**Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> ...r[]{page}\glsnumberformat\@nil**
I think It must have something to do with the \gls command in the glossaries package
`\usepackage{glossaries}`

Comment: @Natalia: Your comment isn't useful,  since your question does not say anything about glossaries

Comment: This only changed the parentheses around the equation number to violet, but the number remains black :'(

Comment: Can I force the color (instead of violet) to take from `hyperref` link color?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: I don't know ... I can take a look, but I stopped my support for TeX.SE basically...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry to hear that! Hope, you'll be back soon...

Answer (score 1):

You just redefine the `\eqref` command as mentioned below and insert the color as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\def\eqref#1{\textcolor{blue}{(\ref{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}


This is a text \eqref{eq1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 11 months, 44 answers. Congratulations. Unfortunately, you still have no clue how to mark up code and rely on others :-(

Comment: Solution matters, formatting doesn't. :)

Comment: Wrong. Both matter. That is why we are using LaTeX (& Co.).

Comment: Actually that only changes the color of the parenthesis, while leaving the color of the text inside the same of the other links

Comment: @Natalia This answer answers the question you asked perfectly fine. What you did not mention, was the use of hyperref along with the `colorlinks` option. I was thinking that you might be speaking about this specifically, but it was not clear. Hence, i just left an upvote to this answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B indeed I was not very clear. Yes I use the hyperrref with the colorlinks option on as in here:
`\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=DarkBlue,anchorcolor=red,pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true}`