# Including parentheses in link to equation

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401083/209090) is proposed a way to color the parentheses when using `\eqref`. However, the parentheses are now not part of the hyperlink. Is there a way to include them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than reinvent the proverbial wheel, I would like to suggest that you (a) load the [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package with the options `nameinlink` and `noabbrev` and (b) use `\labelcref` and `\cref` to generate cross-references to equations; the latter command will prefix the object's type -- here: "equation" -- to the object's number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref} % https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:test}
\labelcref{eq:test}, \cref{eq:test}
\end{document}
```